# Wordpress - insert string with wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code like this:

```
global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'name_of_table',
        array(

            'someInteger' => $surveyResult6,
            'someString' => $surveyResult7
        ),
        array(

            '%d',
            '%s'
        )
    );
    // Increment database rows
    $wpdb->insert_id;
    echo $surveyResult7;
```

...and I have problem with insert string inside my table.

There' s no error, evrything seems to be fine but there's no new record in my database. If I change string to digit and submit form once again, there appear new row with two digits.

I' ve read some topics with problem like this one (wpdb and strings) but I don't find any clue how to fix it. Could anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: remove single quote before `'%d'` , hope this is copy paste error

Answer (score 1):

You  have error in your script

```
global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert(
        'name_of_table',
        array(

            'someInteger' => $surveyResult6,
            'someString' => $surveyResult7
        ),
        array(

            '%d', //<---remove unwanted single quotes
            '%s'
        )
    );
    // Increment database rows
    $wpdb->insert_id;
    echo $surveyResult7;
```

Comment: I take these from Wordpress'es example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb If I remove single quotes I get error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%', expecting ')'"

Comment: check updated answer you also have one extra single quote before `'%d', `

Comment: I removed one, not necesarry single quote before `'%d',` and do what you wrote but sadly it' s still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own problem. I write an answer for people with problem like mine.

I don't know why but if you have (for example) 5 variables in form and one of them is string you have to complete form (all fields). If you skip one of input there' s a problem. The strangest is fact, that if you have only digits as a variables to send to your database, you can skip some fields and code will create row with your and empty values.